# Plural subject and singular predicate

Tags: subjects

I wonder if it's correct to say:

"Graphs are a special data structure."

Here, "graphs" are plural, but "a special data structure" is singular. I remember I have seen this type of sentence before, but I cannot give a reference.

Comment: Yes, the sentence is correct as it is; So is this one: Bananas are a rich source of potassium; But: Ten miles is a long distance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- ？ Graphs are a special data structure.

It's grammatical, but it doesn't parse very well.

Consider this:

- ✔ Apples are a joy to eat.

The problem with the particular sentence in the question is that it's unexpected. Even though the syntax is valid, it's not what we'd *expect* to hear, because on first glance it *appears* to confuse a plurality with a singularity (although it actually doesn't). As such, it's slightly unidiomatic.

One variation that sounds better simply inserts two words:

- Graphs are a special **kind of** data structure.

Other variations replace the verb:

- Graphs **belong to** a special data structure.
- Graphs **share** a special data structure.

Comment: Utterly normal mathematical grammar. _Hausdorff spaces are a type of topological space_. One could use the singular, or not. It's a style matter.